# In maple how do you evaluate combinations?

Tags: maple, computer-algebra-systems

In Maple how do you have it evaluate combinatorics such as $\binom{5}{2}$ and give you the answer 10? (What is the name of what I want to do anyways, is it evaluate?)

Thanks. Seems so easy now that I know. How would you do permutations (and for that matter how do you even write them in LaTex?)?

Comment: `binomial(5,2);` will give the answer 10, or did I miss something obvious?

Comment: `with(combinat): numbperm(3,2);` will give 6.

Answer (score 4):

The calling Sequence in Maple is as follows:

```
[> binomial(5, 2);

10
```

Comment: Short and sweet! +1

Answer (score 2):

Others have already pointed out that a working (plaintext) 1D Maple notation for your example is,

```
binomial(5,2)
```

You can also get a pretty-printed 2D Math input form for this, using either the [palettes](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/expressions/palettes) or command-completion.

Suppose you are in 2D Math input mode (the input cursor will appear slanted, rather than upright, in this mode). That's the default which you may change as a preference, but F5 will also toggle between 1D and 2D input modes on MS-Win and Linux at least.

If you are in 2D Math input mode then there is an item for entering the typeset form of `binomial(5,2)` available in the Expression palette. If you select that entry then a template for it is inserted at the cursor position and you can f[ill in](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/expressions/exppalette) the two arguments for it. Use tab to go from the first to the second.

Alternatively, if you are in 2D Math input mode then you can use [command-completion](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/expressions/completecommand) to get the same template at the cursor position. Type in, `binom` and then activate command-completion. On Linux it is done with `Ctl-Shift-Spacebar`. Select the top item from the popup list that appears.

You can also get expressions such as `binomial(m,n)` to be be typeset similar to LaTeX \binon{m}{n} when they appear as output, but it requires changing a preference. It needs the so-called "extended" typesetting level. You can toggle this preference with the command,

```
interface(typesetting=extended):
```

or you can set the [preference](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/managing/preferences) with the GUI, eg. `Tools-Options->Display->Typesetting level` and save that either globally or just for the current session.